# iOS App Crash on Startup with EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY exception

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

Xamarin based iOS Application crashed with following crash log in Release version. This issue observed in multiple (iPad Air, iPhoneX, iPhone 6s) devices. Not able to replicate this issue in debug or beta mode.

App Crashed before starting app log file. Not able to understand Crash Log. Would you help me to to identify the Crash Log and cause.

> AppVariant:          1:10
>
> Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>
> Role:                Non UI
>
> Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2018-12-09 02:35:13.9818 -0500
>
> Launch Time:         2018-12-09 02:35:10.8014 -0500
>
> OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
>
> Baseband Version:    5.21.00
>
> Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:
>
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00000001bd76b104 __pthread_kill + 8
>
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001bd7e6070 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380 (pthread.c:1492)
>
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00000001bd6c2d78 abort + 140 (abort.c:94)
>
> 3   MyApp                         0x0000000103ec9ca8 0x1025dc000 + 26139816       xamarin_printf (in MyApp) (runtime.m:2335)
>
> 4   MyApp                         0x0000000103dcc464 0x1025dc000 + 25101412       mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (in MyApp) (exception.c:1119)
>
> 5   MyApp                         0x0000000103d83628 0x1025dc000 + 24802856       mono_handle_exception_internal (in MyApp) (mini-exceptions.c:2002)
>
> 6   MyApp                         0x0000000103d823c0 0x1025dc000 + 24798144       mono_handle_exception (in MyApp) (mini-exceptions.c:2288)
>
> 7   MyApp                         0x0000000103d7a084 0x1025dc000 + 24764548       mono_arm_throw_exception (in MyApp) (exceptions-arm64.c:411)
>
> 8   MyApp                         0x0000000102d4e0c8 0x1025dc000 + 7807176        rethrow_exception (in MyApp) + 168
>
> 9   MyApp                         0x00000001028de350 0x1025dc000 + 3154768        MyApp_Application_Main_string__ (in MyApp) (/:1)
>
> 10  MyApp                         0x0000000102d1b798 0x1025dc000 + 7600024        wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr (in MyApp) + 248
>
> 11  MyApp                         0x0000000103d93968 0x1025dc000 + 24869224       mono_jit_runtime_invoke (in MyApp) (mini-runtime.c:2777)
>
> 12  MyApp                         0x0000000103e10950 0x1025dc000 + 25381200       do_runtime_invoke (in MyApp) (object.c:2849)
>
> 13  MyApp                         0x0000000103e13d54 0x1025dc000 + 25394516       do_exec_main_checked (in MyApp) (object.c:4726)
>
> 14  MyApp                         0x0000000103d7678c 0x1025dc000 + 24749964       mono_jit_exec (in MyApp) (driver.g.c:1040)
>
> 15  MyApp                         0x0000000103ed09e8 0x1025dc000 + 26167784       xamarin_main (in MyApp) (monotouch-main.m:0)
>
> 16  MyApp                         0x000000010284dbac 0x1025dc000 + 2562988        main (in MyApp) (main.m:207)
>
> 17  libdyld.dylib

Comment: 1) Symbolize the crash 2) Is there a backtrace associated to this 3) Via the native exception codes, I would *assume* a null object issue (but I do not have your code and the *complete* symbolized crash)

Comment: above logs are symbolized crash log

Comment: Mono symbolized? And the backtrace?

Comment: @SushiHangover it is App code symbolized, thats why not able to find the issue. thread 0 were crashed. above code thread 0 back trace

Answer (score 1):

Device Logs was useful in this analysis. Device log had application crash information. Application was crashed due to null pointer in one of application thread.